# Periodic Orbit on a Nonlinear System

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let the following ODE system be
\begin{align}
x'&=x-y+x^2-2x(x^2+y^2)^\frac{1}{2}
\\
y'&=x+y+xy-2y(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{align}
We can prove easily that $(0,0)$ is the unique equilibrium point. Using the polar coordinates, we can rewrite the system as follows:
\begin{align}
\rho'&=\rho+\rho^2(-2+\cos\theta)
\\
\theta'&=1
\end{align}

Working with the system (for $\theta$ is simple, for $\rho$ we must proceed as a Bernoulli equation), we arrange the following solutions:
\begin{align}
\rho(t)&=\frac{1}{\frac{\cos(\theta_{0}+t)+\sin(\theta_{0}+t)}{2}+2+Ce^{-t}}
\\
\theta&=t+\theta_{0}
\end{align}

Where we can define C for $t=0$ as $C=\frac{1}{\rho_{0}}-2-\frac{\cos\theta_{0}+\sin\theta_{0}}{2}$

The question is, once we have arrived here and we convert into Cartesian coordinates using $\theta_{0}=\arctan(\frac{y_{0}}{x_{0}})$; $\rho_{0}=(x_{0}^2+y_{0}^2)^\frac{1}{2}$, and $x=\rho\cos\theta$; $y=\rho\sin\theta$, how can I find a periodic solution in that system?

Comment: Does $sen \theta = \sin \theta$?

Comment: Yeah, sorry I wrote that as I use to do, but yes.

Comment: Thanks.  Now if you write "sin" as \$\sin \$ you'll get $\sin $!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from the Pablo Luis's result (I didn't check it) :

\begin{align}
\rho(t)&=\frac{1}{\frac{\cos(\theta_{0}+t)+\sin(\theta_{0}+t)}{2}+2+Ce^{-t}}
\\
\theta&=t+\theta_{0}
\end{align}
Obviously the solution is not periodic due to the term $Ce^{-t}$.

But for large $t$ , that is a long time after the start, $Ce^{-t}\to 0$. The solution tends to a periodic function :
$$\rho(t)\simeq\frac{1}{\frac{\cos(\theta_{0}+t)+\sin(\theta_{0}+t)}{2}+2}$$
This is proved by 
$$\rho(t+2k\pi)\simeq\frac{1}{\frac{\cos(\theta_{0}+t+2k\pi)+\sin(\theta_{0}+t+2k\pi)}{2}+2}=\frac{1}{\frac{\cos(\theta_{0}+t)+\sin(\theta_{0}+t)}{2}+2}$$

$$\rho(t+2k\pi)\simeq\rho(t)\qquad t\:\text{ large.}$$
On Cartesian system :
$$\begin{cases}
x(t)\simeq \frac{\cos(\theta_{0}+t)}{\frac{\cos(\theta_{0}+t)+\sin(\theta_{0}+t)}{2}+2}\simeq x(t+2k\pi) \\
y(t)\simeq \frac{\sin(\theta_{0}+t)}{\frac{\cos(\theta_{0}+t)+\sin(\theta_{0}+t)}{2}+2}\simeq y(t+2k\pi) 
\end{cases}\qquad t\:\text{ large.}$$
Eliminating $t$ from the above parametric solution leads to the equation of the limit trajectory which is an ellipse :
$$15(x^2+y^2)-2xy+4(x+y)=4$$

[image]

NOTE :

LutzL points out a sign mistake in the Pablo Luis's equation from which I started my answer (first above equation). Even if it was not correct, the method shows how to proceed in order to find the equation of the steady-state trajectory.

Comparing to the graph from LutzL, apparently one have to rotate the axes of $\pi$ to be consistent with the graph in my answer. The semi-axis lengths $a$ and $b$ agree. The center is symmetrical with respect to the origin.

Comment: So in this case, the periodic solution would be like an ellipse, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. The limit trajectory is an ellipse. The equation is added to my main answer.:

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the period has to be $2\pi$. You should easily see that $ρ(2\pi)=ρ(0)$ demands that $C=0$. That then is all.

---

For the radius equation I get
$$
ρρ'=xx'+yy'=ρ^2(1+x)-2ρ^3 \implies ρ'=ρ-ρ^2(2-\cos θ)
$$
there is no additional sine term. Everything else apart from this change remains the same.

[image]

*red, blue: numerical solutions, gray: $ρ(θ)=\frac2{4-\cosθ-\sinθ}$*

Comment: Yeah, I got confused with another exercise, the polar coordinates are without the sine term.
So when we evaluate for period $2\pi$, we would still have the radius on $\theta$ terms, that would be fine?

Comment: Yes, as long as the angular velocity stays constant $θ'=1$, the period is $2π$.

Comment: There still seems to be an (not really important) sign error in the solution formula for $θ$, I get $-\frac12$ as coefficient for the trig. terms, not $+\frac12$.

Comment: So the periodic solution would be by calculating $x(t+2\pi)=x(t)$, $y(t+2\pi)=y(t)$ ?

Comment: Or $ρ(2π)=ρ(0)$, as the solution formula in polar coordinates is more directly applicable. It reduces to $Ce^{-t}=Ce^{-t-2π}$ with the obvious solution.

Comment: I see, so with this and previously proven by Poincaré-Bendixson theorem on a ring that contains that periodic solution, we should have that this solution is a limit cycle?

Comment: You have explicitly computed that this is a limit cycle. With the explicit solution you have much more insight than just from Poincaré-Bendixson. In general, if there is no exact symbolic solution possible, the invariant ring without stationary points implies the existence of a limit cycle without further computation.